# Using Makefile to export vars from yaml file

Tags: kubernetes, makefile, yq

Like the title says, I have a yaml file with `k:v` format, and I'm using yq to parse the yaml and produce env variables in `k1=v1`, `k2=v2` format. This works great in my shell:

```
$ export $(yq 'to_entries | map(.key + "=" + .value) | join(" ")' app/kube/values.yaml)
$ export
appImageTag=app
appNodePort=30003
appPort=3000
dbImageTag=db
dbName=sage
dbPort=3001
dockerRegistry=trumanpurnell
dockerRepo=sage
```

BUT! I want to do it at the top of my Makefile. I'm so close, I have:

###### Makefile

```
export $(shell yq 'to_entries | map(.key + "=" + .value) | join(" ")' app/kube/values.yaml)

backenv:
    export
```

Which gets me:

```
appImageTag="app="
appNodePort="30003="
appPort="3000="
dbImageTag="db="
dbName="sage="
dbPort="3001="
dockerRegistry="trumanpurnell="
dockerRepo="sage="
```

Ugh, trailing `=`. How to get rid of it? Bonus points for explaining what the difference is?

Comment: Are both these in the same environment? I've found yq to be extremely finicky on syntax and different versions sometimes give wildly different results?

Comment: Same environment, yeah :/

Comment: It is not an issue with the `yq` syntax, but with the Makefile `$(shell)` syntax. It does not produce each of the k/v pair in a new line, it puts it together with a space separating each line.

Comment: An alternate simpler notation in `yq` is just to do `yq -o=shell app/kube/values.yaml`. But what are you trying to do with `export`? Are you defining those variables to re-use within some other command in the same makefile or elsewhere? Because the second option can't work, as the child processes (make process) can never alter the environment of the parent (the shell invoked from)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(foreach var,$(shell yq -o=shell app/kube/values.yaml),$(eval export $(var)))
```

Yields

```
appImageTag=app
appNodePort=30003
appPort=3000
dbImageTag=db
dbName=sage
dbPort=3001
dockerRegistry=trumanpurnell
dockerRepo=sage
```